# Где находить соглашения по codestyle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-style

В различных ЯП есть соглашения по код стайлу

например в названии переменной:
   `_apiBase = 'https://swapi.dev/api'`
**вместо:**
   `apiBase = 'https://swapi.dev/api'`
(нижнее подчёркивание)

Или в **redux** дополнительные данные передаются с именем `payloads`

И это касается не только имен переменных, но иногда и архитектуры проекта, и многое другое

Так вот вопрос в том, где можно ознакомиться со всем этими соглашениями?
Чтобы понимать почему имя переменной с нижнего подчеркивания, почему `payloads`, и тд и тп.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, по крайней мере в JavaScript — такое соглашение является средним арифметическим от целого ряда традиций в разных обществах разработчиков. Некоторые традиции кодифицированы. Например, популярные стилистические руководства:

- https://github.com/airbnb/javascript
- https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react
- https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html
- https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js
- https://standardjs.com/

Проверять код на соответствие популярным соглашениям можно при помощи "линтеров". Иногда в руководствах к ним также перечисляются распространённые практики:

https://github.com/sorrycc/awesome-javascript#qa-tools

Одним из самых популярных сейчас линтеров является ESLint (https://github.com/eslint/eslint). В его документации описываются некоторые правила, ряд из них помечен как рекомендуемые разработчиками линтера. Это тоже может быть полезным чтением: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/